# Issue importing existing Magnolia Front End Project

Tags: magnolia

I have light-modules folder of my project and I have created a page with subpages. I moved to another computer, but I only copied the light module folder and I forgot to export my already created page. Is there a way to bring it back from light-module folder? 
I got the following structure of my light-module folder:

- dialogs
- templates
- webresources

Sorry if my question is lame, but I am completely new to Magnolia.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to bring it back from light-module folder?

No.

Light modules contain templates (and dialogs) and other resources for the page. But the page itself is not part of the modules. If you have access to the other environment, you can export the page and then import it in new system. Otherwise you have to write it again.

If you add `Content Importer` module to your installation, you can use light modules to also carry over pages and other content, but you would still need to export this content manually, and confirm its import from the light module.

Answer (score 0):

To echo what Jan said, and to state in a slightly different way, think of *the pages you create* using your templates as *concrete instances of* those *templates*.  Those concrete instances are stored on some database, while the templates themselves are stored on some file system.